# How to convert any kind of white space to a char?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I use `String.strip()` (Java 11) to remove trailing & leading white spaces from a String. There are 25 different kinds of [white spaces in a String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode). I want to test my code with some of these 25 types of white space.

I have a code example which converts a particular type of white space (ex. `\u2002`) into a `char` and then uses it in a String. When I try to convert another white space type like `\u000A` to char, I get a compiler error. Why does this happen and how to fix it ?

```
public static void main(String...args){
    char chr = '\u2002';//No problem.

    //Compiler error : 
    //Intellij IDEA compiler - Illegal escape character in character literal.
    //Java compiler - java: illegal line end in character literal.
    chr = '\u000a';

    String text = chr + "hello world" + chr;
    text = text.strip();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: For some reason it gets confused by `\u000a` (the code for a newline) in your code. You can use `'\n'` instead.

Comment: @khelwood - thanks. I wonder why '\u000a' does not work. I was thinking of simply copying the values from the wikipedia chart into my code.

Comment: It seems like something about the way source code is parsed converts `\u000a` to a newline, as if you had typed an actual newline in your source code. Since a character literal cannot be spread over two lines, this causes a compile error.

Comment: Kind of related and maybe provides additional information: [Why is executing Java code in comments with certain Unicode characters allowed?](//stackoverflow.com/q/30727515)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're not seeing this error instead?

> error: illegal line end in character literal

Escape sequences like `\u000a` are processed very early in the compilation process. The `\u000a` is being replaced with an actual line feed character (code point 10).

It's as if you wrote this:

```
    chr = '
';
```

which is why, when I try and compile your code using JDK 11.0.8, I get the "illegal line end" error.

This early conversion is described in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4):

> Because Unicode escapes are processed very early, it is not correct to write `'\u000a'` for a character literal whose value is linefeed (LF); the Unicode escape `\u000a` is transformed into an actual linefeed in translation step 1 (§3.3) and the linefeed becomes a LineTerminator in step 2 (§3.4), and so the character literal is not valid in step 3. Instead, one should use the escape sequence `'\n'` (§3.10.6). Similarly, it is not correct to write `'\u000d'` for a character literal whose value is carriage return (CR). Instead, use `'\r'`.

Comment: Thanks. I get different compiler errors, one from intellij IDEA and the other from java compiler. I updated my code comments to mention that now.

Comment: Is there a chart which shows the replacement characters for each of these character literals ?

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6